# Eigenvalue multiplicity of tensor product of positive operator with itself

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $H$ be a separable complex Hilbert space and let $A\in B(H)$ be positive with $||A||=1$ and have eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity 1. Suppose $A=T^*T$ for some $T\in B(H)$. Denote the spectrum of $A$ by $\sigma(A)$. By the main theorem of Brown and Pearcy (1966, download [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-01/S0002-9939-1966-0188786-5/S0002-9939-1966-0188786-5.pdf)<sup>1</sup>): $\sigma(A\otimes A)= \sigma(A)\sigma(A)$, where $\otimes$ denotes the Hilbert tensor product of operators. I am wondering whether this product "preserves the multiplicity" in the sense that the eigenvalue 1 of $A\otimes A$ also has multiplicity 1.

I hoped to prove this as follows. If $e$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 1, then $\{e\}$ is a basis of the corresponding eigenspace $\ker(A-I)$. Then $e\otimes e$ is an eigenvector of $A\otimes A$ with eigenvalue 1. I was hoping to show that $\{e\otimes e \}$ is a basis for the eigenspace, but I haven't been able to show that no other eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 can exist outside the span of $\{e\otimes e\}$.

<sup>1</sup>*Brown, Arlen; Pearcy, Carl*, [**Spectra of tensor products of operators**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2035080), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 17, 162-166 (1966). [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035080), [ZBL0141.32202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0141.32202), [MR188786](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=188786).

Comment: You can do this using the spectral theorem.  This reduces to the case where your operator is multiplication by a continuous function on a compact space, a situation wheŕe the result is transparent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @terceira. I can reduce this to considering $A$ to be a multiplication $\psi_F$ by some bounded function $F$ on $L^2(\mu)$ for some finite measure space $(M, F, \mu)$. I don't know the appropriate spectral theorem to reduce it further to the case that $F$ is continuous and $M$ is compact, but in either case I don't quite see how to show that $\psi_F$ having eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity 1 implies that $\psi_F\otimes \psi_F$ must also have eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity 1. What transparent insight am I missing?

Comment: I gave it a bit more thought and you were right: it is transparent! Once you've seen through it, that is.